# Set-Cookie doesn't set cookies (backend: nodejs, frontend: react)

Tags: reactjs, node.js, cookies, response-headers

I had a assignment where I had to implement Login / Logout functionality.

The app was very simple, so I used the very simple approach.

While I was working on localhost - everything went well)
But after deployment on Glitch - cookies stopped working well.

My code:

**request:**

```
request(
  url,
  method,
  body,
  credentials = 'include',
  mode = 'cors',
  headers = { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
)
```

**server.js:**

```
const http = require('http');
const app = require('./app');
const server = http.createServer(app);
```

**app.js**

```
const cors = require('cors');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
 
const app = express();
 
app.use(
  cors({
    credentials: true,
    exposedHeaders: [
      'Set-Cookie',
      'Authorization',
      'Origin',
      'X-Requested-With',
      'Content-Type',
      'Accept',
    ],
    origin: 'https://assignment-artem-zakharchuk.vercel.app/',
  })
);
app.use(cookieParser());
```

**user.controller.js**

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
 
 
async function httpLoginUser(req, res) {
  const { email } = req.body;
  
  const existUser = await checkIfUserExists(email);
  const jwt = new JWT(process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET);
  const payload = { user: existUser[0] };
  const options = { expiresIn: '14d' };
  const token = jwt.generate(payload, options);
  res.cookie('login', token, { maxAge: 1209600000 });
  res.status(201).json({ error: false, token: token });
}
```

When the response come I see my cookie in response Headers => Set-Cookie.

But the Application=>Cookie is blank.

Maybe someone knows how to deal with it?

I am not experienced well, so please if you answer, don't be ashamed to use more examples)

Comment: You should also set the samesite attribute when dealing with cookies. I did post a blog post about how to troubleshoot cookie problems at https://nestenius.se/2023/10/09/debugging-cookie-problems/

Comment: Thank you, Tore. Without you, I would not make it. My problem was in response ***res.cookie('login', token, { maxAge: 1209600000, sameSite: 'none', secure: true }) *** There was no information about sameSite and secure. Now the token is set. but does not read))) Very cool article!

Comment: In general , storing tokens in the browser is a bad idea , see this video. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lEnbi4KClVw&t=2580s

I would handle authentication on a separate page, not inside the sam SPA application, so just redirect the user to the login page when he is not logged in?

Comment: Tore, I don't want to take advantage of your openness, as well as you to spend too much time on me.
But in the video, you shared there is a lot of new information which my brain refused to understand in the complex.
And I am not sure If I divided it into small blocks correctly, please check:

1. You can use tokens in session storage only in extreme cases for short periods and don't include into token any sensitive information;
2. It is better to use BFF or as you told Oath2;
3. In future I need to dive deeper into questions like OWASP.

Comment: Yes, its a complex world and the general idea is that if you have security minded, then keeping tokens away from the browser can be a good idea, because first, its impossible to secure the tokens in the browser.

Comment: Second that managing tokens in the browser will make the browser app more complicated. So by offloading the work to the backend, the frontend client becomes simpler. .. So, its all about tradeoff and being aware of the problems. then its up to you to decide and make the tradeofs. Here is a second video on the topic. https://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2022/05/12/securing-spas-and-blazor-applications-using-the-bff-pattern-recording/

Answer (score 0):

thank you Tore once again!
Your article helped very much!

I had a task: changing the interface depending on whether the user is logged in or not.
I wanted to implement this by setting and reading cookies.
If you are trying to do the same - please forget it)

the better way, according to my above code is to change the frontend code.
after the "/login" request I used sessionStorage to save my token.

sessionStorage.setItem('login', postData.token);

and after this, I just had to receive it
sessionStorage.getItem('login');

now everything works correctly!